# How to break selection by paragraphs (Medium like) in an iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

How to separate paragraphs inside a `UITextView` into completely isolated text clusters such as when doing selection you can only select words inside that paragraph?

In this case you could only select text "**You obliged.** "

[image]

I´m experimenting with selection cancelation when outside the paragraph, doing the required maths to define paragraph scope, but no luck so far.

Comment: This is a very broad question. :(

Comment: @Abizern What would you suggest? I don't know how to make it more specific :( . I just want that kind of functionality on my richTextEditor and I don´t know where to start.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that you're listing a set of requirements and asking for a solution. A better method might be to break down the question into smaller parts.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that then

Comment: @Abizern I have made some improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The idea is to locate extension of current paragraph from cursor
>   position when starting to select the text. Then allow only the
>   intersection between ranges of the paragraph and the one corresponding to the selection.

---

**This is the solution as of Swift 3**

---

```
class RichTextView: UITextView {...}

extension RichTextView: UITextViewDelegate {

  func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let range = textView.selectedRange
    if range.length > 0 {
     if let maxRange = 
       textView.attributedText.getParagraphRangeContaining(cursorPosition: range.location){
          selectedRange = NSIntersectionRange(maxRange, range)
      }
    }
  }
}

extension NSAttributedString {

    func getParagraphRangeContaining(cursorPosition: Int) -> NSRange? {
        let cursorPosition = cursorPosition - 1

        let nsText = self.string as NSString
        let textRange = NSMakeRange(0, nsText.length)

        var resultRange : NSRange?
        nsText.enumerateSubstrings(in: textRange, options: .byParagraphs, using: {
            (substring, substringRange, _, _) in

            if (NSLocationInRange(cursorPosition , substringRange)) {
                resultRange = substringRange
                return
            }
        })
        return resultRange
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, I would try creating a `UITextView` for each paragraph and positioning them correctly. Create a new one when the user presses enter (and make sure to preserve the text after their cursor), and join the contents of the two adjacent views if they press delete with their cursor positioned at the beginning of the second one.

That way, selection would work in each view, but the user could not select across two views at once.

Comment: I have been thinking about this possibility, but it seems a bit overkill, I guess it may be an easier way to achieve it.

Comment: I will grant you the bounty so it's not lost, if you feel like supporting your idea with code.. that will be great.

Comment: Now that I see it, I think that the other answer is a better answer for most situations. This answer will give you a bit more customization, but i think the other one is still better.